# Rotation of $3$-dimensional space vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, 3d, rotations

Assuming there are two vectors $P(x_p,y_p,z_p)$ and $Q(x_q,y_q,z_q)$ originating from the origin. Now, if I rotate vector $P$ to another position in space and obtain the coordinates $P'(x_p',y_p',z_p')$, how can I use the same rotation rule to obtain the coordinates of the rotated vector $Q'$? Can anyone provide me with some assistance?

for example, $P=(4,0,0)$, when we rotate $P$, assume we get $P′=(2,2,2\sqrt{2})$
, so if $Q=(1,2,3)$
, what $Q'$ is ?

Comment: There can be many possible "rotation rules" from $P$ to $P'$, even as simple as $P = P' = (1,0,0)$.

Comment: If $R$ is a rotation matrix such that $P'=RP$, then, assuming I understand the question correctly, $Q'=RQ$. The action of premultiplying any vector originating from the origin by $R$ rotates the vector by a certain angle along a specified axis of rotation. In other words, if $R$ rotates $P$ along an axis given by some vector $A\in \mathbb{R}^3$ by angle $\theta$, $R$ rotates $Q$ along the same axis $A$ by the same angle $\theta$.

Comment: for example, $P = (4,0,0)$ , when we rotate $P$, assume we get $P' = (2,2,2\sqrt{2})$, so if $Q = (1,2,3)$, what Q' is ?

Comment: You seem to think that there is a unique answer. Why? Peterwhy explained that not to be the case. Another simple way to see this even if we fix the rotation $R$ somehow, we can precompose it with any rotation $R'$ about the axis $OP$. Then $R\circ R'$ will stil map $P$ to $P'$, but it may map $Q$ somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $P$ is not parallel to $P'$, the unit-length axis of rotation is $k=\frac{P\times P'}{\lvert 
P\times P' \rvert}$, where $\times$ denotes the vector cross product. To find the angle of rotation, use dot product property $P \cdot P'=\lvert P\rvert\lvert P'\rvert \cos(\theta) $ to find the angle $\theta=\arccos\left(\frac{P\cdot P'}{\lvert P \rvert \lvert P' \rvert}\right)$ between $P$ and $P'$.

According to the "Matrix Notation" section of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) Wikipedia article, the corresponding rotation matrix $R(k,\theta)$ is given by expression $I+\sin(\theta)[ k]_{\times}+(1-\cos(\theta))[k]_{\times}^2$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and the notation $[\cdot]_{\times}$ is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Cross_product). This expression for $R$ is the referred to as the "matrix form of Rodrigues' rotation formula."

In other words, $Q'=R(k,\theta)Q$.

For speed, however, a computer implementation of this sort of axis-angle rotation should use quaternions instead of rotation matrices.

**Edit**: As noted by @peterwhy in the comments below, the above answer assumes that $P$ is not parallel to $P'$ and that we are looking for the unique axis of rotation $k$ and angle $\theta\in(0,\pi)$ such that the space curve $R(k,t)P$ from $P$ to $P'$ is a subset of the plane $\text{span}(P,P')$, where $t\in[0,\theta]$.

If we remove the 'space curve' requirement, we can uniquely determine a rotation axis $k$ and angle $\theta\in(0,\pi)$ given *two* pairs of vectors $P_1, P_1'$ and $P_2, P_2'$ such that $P_1,P_1'$ are not parallel and $P_2,P_2'$ are not parallel and $P_2$ and $P_2'$ do not have mirror symmetry over the plane bisecting $P_1$ and $P_1'$, i.e., $P_2'\neq 2 \frac{X\cdot P_2}{X\cdot X}X   -P_2$, where $X=P_2-\left(P_2\cdot \frac{P_1'-P_1}{|P_1'-P_1|}\right)\frac{P_1'-P_1}{|P_1'-P_1|}$, the projection of $P_2$ onto the plane bisecting $P_1$ and $P_1'$.

Now, for convenience, let $k_0=\frac{(P_1'-P_1)\times(P_2'-P_2)}{|(P_1'-P_1)\times(P_2'-P_2)|}$. Assuming that $P_1,P_1'$ are not parallel and $P_2,P_2'$ are not parallel, if any non-undefined entry in element-wise division $\frac{k_0}{(P_1-(P_1\cdot k_0)k_0)\times(P_1'-(P_1'\cdot k_0)k_0)}$ is positive, $k=k_0$. Otherwise, $k=-k_0$. The corresponding angle $\theta$ is given by $\theta=\arccos\left(\frac{(P_1-(P_1\cdot k)k)\cdot(P_1'-(P_1'\cdot k)k)}{|(P_1-(P_1\cdot k)k)||(P_1'-(P_1'\cdot k)k)|}\right)$. If $\arccos\left(\frac{(P_1-(P_1\cdot k)k)\cdot(P_1'-(P_1'\cdot k)k)}{|(P_1-(P_1\cdot k)k)||(P_1'-(P_1'\cdot k)k)|}\right)\neq\arccos\left(\frac{(P_2-(P_2\cdot k)k)\cdot(P_2'-(P_2'\cdot k)k)}{|(P_2-(P_2\cdot k)k)||(P_2'-(P_2'\cdot k)k)|}\right)$,  however, there is no axis or angle sending $P_1$ to $P_1'$ and $P_2$ to $P_2'$.

Note that there is likely a faster way than the one shown here to compute $k$ and $\theta$ under these new assumptions.

**Edit 2:** If instead given that $P_1=P_1'$ and $P_2$ is not parallel to $P_2'$, the method above the first edit section can be used on $P_1,P_1'$ to obtain $k$ and $\theta$. If $k$ is not parallel to $P_2\times P_2'$, however, there is no axis or angle sending $P_1$ to $P_1'$ and $P_2$ to $P_2'$.

If instead $P_1=P_1'$ and $P_2=-P_2'$, $k=\frac{P_1}{|P_1|}$ and $\theta=\pi$.

If instead $P_1=-P_1'$ and $P_2=-P_2'$, $\theta=\pi$ and $k=\frac{P_1\times P_2}{|P_1\times P_2|} $.

Finally, if instead $P_1$ is not parallel to $P_1'$ and $P_2=-P_2'$, $\theta = \pi$ and $k=\frac{P_2\times(P_1'-P_1)}{|P_2\times(P_1'-P_1)|}$.

I can go into more detail regarding the derivation and intuition behind the statements in "Edit" and "Edit 2" at @ZHIHA's request.

Comment: I use matlab code to verify, but not right
P = [4,0,0];
Q = [1,2,3];
P1 = [2,2,2*sqrt(2)];
cP = cross(P, P1);
dP = dot(P, P1);
theta = acos(dP/(norm(P)*norm(P1)));
crossProductMatrix = [0, -cP(3), cP(2);
                     cP(3), 0, -cP(1);
                     -cP(2), cP(1), 0];
R = eye(3) + sin(theta) * crossProductMatrix + (1-cos(theta))*crossProductMatrix*crossProductMatrix;
Q1 = R * Q';
distance1 = sqrt((P(1) - Q(1)).^2 + (P(2) - Q(2)).^2 + (P(3) - Q(3)).^2);
distance2 = sqrt((P1(1) - Q1(1)).^2 + (P1(2) - Q1(2)).^2 + (P1(3) - Q1(3)).^2);
disp(distance1);
disp(distance2);

Comment: Sorry; I made a mistake. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you're so kind! If possible, could you give me some hints about implementing the quaternions method?

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Used_methods, a fast-to-compute quaternion-based expression for $Q'$ is $Q+2k\times (k\times Q + 2 \cos\left( \frac{\theta}{2} \right) Q)$.

Comment: Very good answer. @ZHIHA: You should "upvote" this answer. Click on the arrow pointing upwards. And welcome to Math.SE!

Comment: Why must the axis of rotation be perpendicular to both $P$ and $P'$? The minimum requirement is that the two angles are equal: 1) between $k$ and $P$, and 2) between $k$ and $P'$. One may also choose $k$ parallel to $\frac{P+P'}{2}$, and $\theta = \pi$.

Comment: @peterwhy That is true. I assumed that property about the axis of rotation in my answer to get a unique result.

Comment: @peterwhy Are the two axes of rotation mentioned so far the only ones for which there exists $\theta$ sending $P$ to $P'$, assuming that $P\neq P'$ and $P$ and $P'$ are not parallel?

Comment: Any non-zero vector on the perpendicular bisector plane between $P$ and $P'$ can be an axis of rotation.

Answer (score 1):

As peterwhy noted in his comments, an **axis of rotation** for the pair $P$ and $P'$ is any line that lies in the perpendicular bisecting plane of the line segment $PP'$.  This plane has the equation

$ n \cdot (r - m ) = 0 $

where $r = [x,y,z]^T , n = P - P' , m = \dfrac{1}{2} (P + P') $

To specify the axis, pick a point in this plane, any point.  Let's call it $P_0$.  This will be a point through which the axis passes.  Also, pick a direction for the axis line.  This can be found as follows

$ a = \cos \psi \ u_1 + \sin \psi \ u_2 $

where $ \psi $ is arbitrary, and $u_1, u_2$ are two mutually perpendicular unit vectors that are also perpendicular to $n$, that is,

$ u_1 \cdot n = u_2 \cdot n = u_1 \cdot u_2 = 0 $ and $ u_1 \cdot u_1 = u_2 \cdot u_2 = 1 $

Next, we have to find the angle of rotation.  This is found by projecting the points $P$ and $P'$ onto the plane passing through $P_0$ and having a normal vector $a$, or equivalently projecting vectors $P_0 P $ and $P_0 P'$ onto the plane passing through the origin and perpendicular to the axis line of action $a$.  The projection matrix is

$ \mathbf{U} = ( I_3 - {a a}^T ) $

Hence, we have the following two vectors,

$ w_1 = \mathbf{U} (P_0 P) $ and $w_2 = \mathbf{U} (P_0 P')  $

The angle of rotation $ \phi $ satisfies

$ w_1 \cdot w_2 = \| w_1 \| \| w_2 \| \cos \phi $

This gives $ \phi $ up to a sign.  To determine the sign of $\phi$ form the vector

$ V = w_1 \times w_2 $

If $ a \cdot V \gt 0 $ then $\phi \gt 0$ and if $ a \cdot V \lt 0 $ then $\phi \lt 0$.

That's all we need to find a possible image of the point $Q$.  This follows from [Rodrigues' Rotation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#Statement) in which the image of vector $v$ is $v'$ given by

$ v' = v \cos \phi + (a \times v) \sin \phi + a ( a \cdot v) (1 - \cos \phi) $

This formula is for a vector $v$ having its tail at the origin, and an axis of rotation $a$ (a unit vector) that passes through the origin.

In our context, the above formula has to be modified slightly, to take into consideration that our axis of rotation passes through $P_0$, so by shifting everything by $-P_0$, rotating, then shifting back to $P_0$, we get the final form of the image $Q'$ as follows:

$ Q' = P_0 + (Q - P_0) \cos \phi + (a \times (Q - P_0)) \sin \phi + a ( a \cdot (Q - P_0)) (1 - \cos \phi) $

Comment: Is $P_0$ on $a$?

Comment: The axis passes through $P_0$ and its direction vector is $a$.

Comment: Would it also be correct to find $w_1,w_2$ by projecting $P$ and $P'$ onto the plane normal to $a$ passing through the origin?

Comment: What is the motivation for the final step that shifts by $-P_0$, rotates, etc.?

Comment: As for your first question, about projection.  What I am doing is projecting $P$ and $P'$ onto a plane passing through $P_0$.  Equivalently you could project $P_0 P$ and $P_0 P'$ onto a plane (with normal vector $a$) passing through the origin.  I'll edit my solution to correct the error.  As for your second question, the rotation formula is applicable where the axis passes through the origin.  This explains the necessary shift.  Thanks for pointing out these issues.

Comment: I think I understand now, but I just want to make sure: does the axis $a$ does not necessarily pass through the origin?

Comment: I asked "Would it be also correct to find $w_1 ...$" because I assumed that the axis of rotation passed through the origin.

Comment: No, the axis doesn't have to pass through the origin, it passes through $P_0$ , which is an arbitrary point that lies on the perpendicular bisecting plane of the line segment $P P'$.